# reconnect default database man studio SQL express (4064 error)

Tags: sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-express

I have SQL Server 2008 Express and Management Studio installed on my laptop

I get an error:

> Cannot open user default database. Login failed

I've been googling for hours trying to resolve this but I'm well out of my depth

I can't log on to master or any other database.

I am sure I have disconnected the default database.

How do I get it back /  reconnect it?

Comment: thanks im reading it now

Comment: didnt help becoz i'm talking about 'local' sqlexpress instal.....   another hour or so and disappointed to be non-the-wiser....  decided will be easier/quicker to just reinstall everything :(